# What is returned from a java.net.URLConnection with a HTTPS URL? Is the result encrypted?

Tags: java, encryption, https, urlconnection

I am using `java.net.URLConnection`, many of the URLs that I am passing into it use the HTTPS protocol. Is it safer to make the request using the HttpsURLConnection class or if it's still possible to get the benefit of encryption if one uses the URLConnection class.

Comment: To those who voted to close: I don't believe that this is a bad question, it was just badly worded.

Comment: @monsky I do not agree. The question asks about a choice that cannot be made. No amount of rewording can fix that.

Comment: I don't think the orginial poster knew that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a real question. You don't get the choice. The URLConnection returned by URL.openConnection() for HTTPS: URLs *is* an HttpsURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect a URLConnection to an https URL, it will either connect using HTTPS or produce an error [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29).

Comment: Almost, but you don't 'connect a URLConnection'. You *create* it, from a URL, and at that point it is *already* associated with the string in that URL, HTTPS or otherwise.

Comment: Well, yes, but it doesn't actually open the connection when you call `openConnection`, only when `connect` is called.

Comment: Indeed, but you still don't connect it to a URL. It's the other way around. The URL provides the URLConnection object.